# eclipse stops responding while running a .jsp file

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

i have created a basic dynamic web project in eclipse.
my jsp file contains following code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
   this is the sum of 5 and 3 <%com.testing.SumOfNumbers.addTwoNumbers(3,5); %>
</body>
</html>
```

and in package "com.testing" i have created SumOfNumbers class with addTwoNumbers method.

```
package com.testing;

public class SumOfNumbers {
        public static int addTwoNumbers(int a,int b)
        {
            return a+b;
        }
}
```

i have downloaded tomcat v10.0 server.
I tried several times but same result. I don't know where the problem is ,is it in tomcat server or eclipse bug?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely to be your code, although you're using a scriptlet instead of an expression, so the sum won't be in the output like you seem to expect.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock includes directions on how to get a stack dump to see what's going on.